# Typescript mapped type with interfaces using "key in keyof"

Tags: typescript

I have this interface:

```
interface REDUX_STATE {
  APP: APP,
  AUTH: AUTH,
}
```

And I need to define a type for the `UPDATE_ACTIONS` object which is something like this:

```
const UPDATE_ACTIONS = {
  APP: "UPDATE_APP",
  AUTH: "UPDATE_AUTH"
}
```

So It's obvious that this type should have the **same properties** of `REDUX_STATE`, which is this example are `APP` and `AUTH`.

I found out that I can do this with `type` and it works

```
type UPDATE_ACTIONS = {
  [key in keyof REDUX_STATE]: string
}
```

But I cannot define it as an `interface`, like:

```
interface UPDATE_ACTIONS {
  [key in keyof REDUX_STATE]: string
}
```

I get this error:

[image]

Is there a way this could be done using an interface?

Comment: I've also found this issue on Typescript Github repo. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13573 . It seems that this is not possible, but might be in the future.

Comment: Why do you need to do it in an interface if the type works?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So far i've been `type` aliases for unions and arrays. And Interfaces for objects. Also Typescrip docs recommend using interface over type aliases whenever possible: _Because an interface more closely maps how JavaScript object work by being open to extension, we recommend using an interface over a type alias when possible._ [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: Are you aware that the way your first snippet works, `APP` and `AUTH` are also used as types/interfaces? I dont know what keeps you from writing `const UPDATE_ACTIONS: REDUX_STATE`

Comment: @MikeS. Hi Mike, `APP` and `AUTH` have their own types in `REDUX_STATE`. Both are interfaces. thanks.

Comment: Gotcha, sadly you can't have union types aka `"APP" | "AUTH"` as an indexing signature. The typescript compiler actually suggests using a mapped object type instead. See [this playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/MYewdgzgLgBAqgBQCIEEAqBRA+igwmgSQHkA5AZRgF4YBvAKBhhQQQC4YAiRVTHFjgDQMmcNAAl2XZOmwpRYjnQC+dOgEswUAKYAnAGYBDYFvjTeeQqQr1GAbQDWWgJ7tHTkHphQnABy0fTHll8YnIAXXZoHQ0Ac2UgA)