# When can't I use `[key in SOME_UNION_TYPE]` as the top level property of an interface?

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-typings

Given this union type that I need to use as keys:

```
type MY_KEYS = "PROP_A" | "PROP_B" | "PROP_C";
```

Why does using `type` alias work:

```
type MY_TYPE_OBJECT = {
  [key in MY_KEYS]: string
}
```

And using `interface` does not work:

```
interface MY_INTERFACE_OBJECT {
  [key in MY_KEYS]: string
}
```

Error that I get:

[image]

And the weirdest thing is that this works just fine (when `[key in MY_KEYS]` is nested):

```
interface MY_INTERFACE_OBJECT_V2 {
  [key: string]: {
    [key in MY_KEYS]: string
  }
}
```

**QUESTION**

Why does it work as a nested property and it does not work as the top level property of the interface?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63375410/typescript-mapped-type-with-interfaces-using-key-in-keyof#comment112068114_63375410 ?

Comment: @MikeS. thanks, Mike. That question is also mine. I will delete this one. But there is something I don't understand. Why does `[key in MY_KEYS]` work as a nested property? Isn't it working as a `index` signature after all? What is the difference between the top-level property and a nested property in that case?

Comment: The difference is, you are providing a type definition nested inside the interface definition. Inside the nested TYPE definition this is allowed, in the INTERFACE definition it is not.